# Reset formatting in place of existing FlowDocument/Paragraph object

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, richtextbox, paragraph

I've searched the Internet high and low so any help the community could lend is mighty appreciated.

Is there a way to change and even reset all formatting (bold, colors, etc.) in a `Paragraph` object within a `RichTextBox` from code behind?  I have a `RichTextBox` that I'm applying syntax and error highlighting to lines (each line represented by a `Paragraph`) and I want to be able to revert or change the formatting in place so `TextPointers` to selected text can be reselected seamlessly.  For example I want to be able to do bracket matching much like Visual Studio does without the user having their caret appear at the beginning or end of a line.

Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

[This answer almost gets me there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493829/paragraph-formatting-in-a-wpf-richtextbox)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing to know is that the `TextRange` constructor takes two `TextPointer` objects as start and end. Those objects don't have to be tied to the selection in any way, and they have methods like `GetPositionAtOffset` to move through the content.

Here's some sample code to reset the font family, bold, and italic in the paragraph where the user's caret is, without changing the selection at all:

```
var para = richTextBox.CaretPosition.Paragraph;
var range = new TextRange(para.ContentStart, para.ContentEnd);
range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, "Calibri");
range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);
range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Normal);
```